# A "Take a Square Root When You Can" conjecture related to the prime factorization

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

I would tend to think that the following has already been investigated.

But as implied from the title, I have no idea how to even start looking for it.

---

Let $P_n$ denote the sum of the squares of the prime factors of $n$ with multiplicity; i.e.

> let $\ S\ $ be a finite set of primes. Let $\ e: S\rightarrow\{1\ 2\ ...\}\ $ represents positive integer exponents in $\ n\ :=\ \prod_{p\in S}\ p^{e(p)}.\ $ Then
>
> $$P_n\ :=\ \sum_{p\in S}\ e(p)\cdot p^2$$

Let $A_n$ denote the following sequence (defined for every $n>1$):

$
 A_n=
 \begin{cases}
  \sqrt{P_n} & \text{$\sqrt{P_n}    \in\mathbb{N}$}\\
       {P_n} & \text{$\sqrt{P_n}\not\in\mathbb{N}$}\\
 \end{cases}
$

A few examples:

- $A_{5}=\sqrt{5^2}=5$
- $A_{30}=2^2+3^2+5^2=38$
- $A_{48}=\sqrt{2^2+2^2+2^2+2^2+3^2}=5$
- $A_{60}=2^2+2^2+3^2+5^2=42$

---

Now, form a sequence by performing this operation repeatedly, beginning with any positive integer $k>1$, and taking the result at each step as the input to the next. My conjecture is that this process will eventually reach a number $n$ such that $A_n=n$, regardless of which positive integer $k$ is chosen initially.

For example, an initial value of $k=9$ yields the following process:

- $A_{9}=3^2+3^2=18$
- $A_{18}=2^2+3^2+3^2=22$
- $A_{22}=2^2+11^2=125$
- $A_{125}=5^2+5^2+5^2=75$
- $A_{75}=3^2+5^2+5^2=59$
- $A_{59}=\sqrt{59^2}=59$

---

It's easy to observe that $A_n=n$ for every prime number $n$ ("landing" on the 1st case).

In addition to that, $A_n=n$ also for the non-prime $n=27$ ("landing" on the 2nd case).

I am pretty sure that $A_n\neq{n}$ for any other value of $n$, but I do not know how to prove this.

It would be nice if someone suggested a proof, although it is not the primary question at hand.

In any case, this conjecture seems much more probable than the $3n+1$ conjecture, since the latter has to "land" on a power of $2$, while the former can "land" on any prime number (or $27$), which is significantly more likely to occur within any given range.

However, the process seems to be growing up to rather large figures for certain initial values of $k$, such as $30$ and $60$ (and many others), so it may be possible to refute this conjecture by showing an initial value of $k$ for which the process never terminates.

---

So at this point I can consider three different approaches:

1. Prove that the process converges for every initial value
2. Prove that the process diverges for some initial value
3. Show that the process loops for some initial value

The first two options seem quite difficult, and I wouldn't even know where to start.

The third option is the easiest, but I find it very unlikely that such initial value exists.

So any ideas or points of reference to related researches will be highly appreciated.

Comment: $A_{16}=4$, I will remove the notion that $A_{16}=16$.

Comment: I do not actually understand how $9-18-22-125-59$ is possible.$3$ is the only prime divisor of $9$ so $A_9$=3

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas: Prime factorization $\equiv$ non-distinct primes.

Comment: I believe you should mention this,that the prime factors could be equal.

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas: I agree, but I thought that the examples given before $A_9$ made it extremely obvious.

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas: What's the down-vote for?????

Comment: I did not give you the downvote.

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas: OK, I forgot the automatic down-voting-without-a-comment algorithm running in the background of this website. I'll see if I can remove my entire profile into http://math.stackexchange.com. Thanks.

Comment: I too don't understand 9-18, can you write it explicitly? In A_30 you have 2^2.

Comment: @joro: OK, but please take a look at $A_{48}$ and $A_{60}$ and tell me what you see (BTW, I am a little reluctant to edit the question, because I've noticed that questions here are down-voted immediately after being edited).

Comment: @Daniel Soltész: Thanks. I wrote at the top of the question that I wasn't really sure what proper title I should give it. If you have any suggestions then I'll be happy to hear them.

Comment: I already checked the first 20000 integers for 2-3-4 cycles (no such cycles in this interval) without multiplicity when I saw that you do count them with multiplicity.

Comment: I don't understand the part where you write $\sqrt{59}=59$. Could you edit it please so it says what you actually mean to say?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Sorry, just a typo. Should be $\sqrt{59^2}=59$. Now fixed. BTW, there's really no need to down-vote the question just for this obvious typo (obvious, because $A_{59}=59$ according to the definition of $A_n$).

Comment: Who said anything about downvoting for a typo? Why so sensitive to downvotes?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Well, obviously because it's quite annoying to write-down a pretty elaborated and detailed question, and then getting down-votes **without** any comment explaining them. I'd happily accept criticism if there is something wrong in it, but I don't see any excuse for just going around down voting other people's effort (which seems to be quite a habit on this website in particularly BTW). Anyway, sorry for assuming that it was you. Thanks for the previous correction.

Comment: "...and then getting down-votes without any comment explaining them...." You have **one** downvote on this question. Not "down-votes"; **one** downvote. Get over it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Haha :) I didn't even know you could see how many down-votes a post had (I just remembered the rep from the day before). There was one more earlier but I guess it was revoked or something... Anyway, my general point is that it seems to happen in pretty much every question I ever post here (and yes - with no comments). I guess I should probably stick to math.stackexchange, the community there seems to be a little more cooperative and less hostile than in here...

Comment: The question to me seems contrived. $P_n$ could be defined without multiplicities, or with a power higher than 2 (and $A_n$ then the corresponding root) or in any number of ways that sends a prime to itself and that seems likely to send infinitely many integers into primes. Unless this particular formulation arises from some other problem (eg. if $P_n$ were a well studied arithmetic function), why is it interesting? In itself it lacks the beauty and tantalizing mix of approachability and inaccessibility of the $3x+1$ conjecture.

Comment: @YaakovBaruch: 1. I don't think that this conjecture is "more accessible" than the $3n+1$ conjecture (if you really consider inaccessibility as something of beauty). 2. My interest in this question originally arose from a previous issue that I had been looking into, with regards to sequences of consecutive integers, such that for every integer - the square root of the sum of the squares of its prime factors is integer by itself. [That other question](http://mathoverflow.net/q/192282/27456) was an attempt to depict every integer as an $n$-dimensional rectangle, and then measure its diagonal.

Comment: A minor quibble: I don’t think you want $S$ to be a *finite* set of primes.